# The JAR file C:\sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking attach source below

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting an error stating:

```
The JAR file C:\sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking attach source below.
```

However I've clicked the attach source button and added C:\sdk\platforms\android-17\android.jar and then it simply gives me:

```
Source not found. The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Activity.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below.
```

Comment: That is not the **source**, but the compiled code itself in a JAR file ... You need to get the source. Usually <jarname>-src.zip...

Answer (score 15):

First make sure that you've downloaded the source files for the version of android that you're using in the project via the Android SDK Manager: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Then right-click on your project and choose properties, pick "Java Build Path" from the left menu, pick the "Libraries" tab on the right, click to expand "Android X.X.X", click to expand "android.jar", and then double-click the "Source attachment:" item.

In the pop-up, choose the "External Location", click "External Folder", and browse to your android-sdk/sources/android-xx that is appropriate for the "Android X.X.X" selected earlier.  Choose OK to close the dialogs, and you should be set!

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a second jarfile containing the source code (.java) files for the given library. As in ppeterka's comment, this will usually be named something like "android-src.jar". In your example, you actually used a different version of the binary jarfile, which won't contain source files.

Specifically for obtaining the Android SDK sources, the Android SDK Manager tool should allow you to download them easily: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Once those are downloaded, you'll need to find the path to the right jar/zip file(s) and reattach the correct source.

Comment: I have it downloaded according to the SDK Manager tool but I couldn't find android-src.jar. I followed these instructions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727049/activity-class-class-file-editor-the-jar-file-c-sdk-platforms-android-17-and and added C:/sdk/platforms/android-17 but it's still doing the same thing